# What is a single word that describes "(excessive) human desire for external validation" (i.e., popularity)?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, excessive human desire for sex is lust, and the excessive human desire for food is gluttony; however, pride does not quite describe the human desire for external validation rather it mostly describes the personal feeling of accomplishment, so I was wondering if there is a specific word for the desire for external validation from other people or in general someone can shed some light on these concepts.

Comment: It takes *low self-esteem* to need excessive outer validation. But you have used the current meaning of **pride** (in one's work) as the pleasure "of accomplishment." The old sin of pride is being puffed up, haughty, snobbish: Don't let pride get in your way if you need the job. Ain't Too Proud To Beg.

Comment: "Instagram model"

Comment: to be more clear I am referring to a very recent and popular trend of seeking large-scale status and popularity by say having high social media followers (e.g., Dan Bilzerian) or seeking to collaborate online with popular figures (e.g., YouTubers who interview people like Dan Bilzerian) and so on. For example, can we say in common English that people like Dan Bilzerian are seeking vanity?

Answer (score 42):

That's ***vanity***. This term is

> used to describe something that is done ***with the aim of getting praise, fame, or approval*** rather than for serious or good reasons
>
> - The new bridge was quickly condemned as a "pointless ***vanity*** project", intended to enhance the reputation of the mayor. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vanity))

Here is how Jane Austen differentiates ***pride*** from ***vanity*** in *[Pride and Prejudice](http://www.literaturepage.com/read.php?titleid=prideandprejudice&abspage=16&bookmark=1)*:

> - Vanity and pride are different things, though the words are often used synonymously. A person may be ***proud*** without being ***vain***. *Pride relates more to our opinion of ourselves*, ***vanity to what we would have others think of us***.

Comment: Thank you for the great and detailed explanation. English is not my first language, but I am surprised that even though represents a core concept, vanity does not seem to be a popular word. I have two questions about this:

1) is there a more colloquial version that everyday people might use?
2) do you know any appearance of this word or its equivalents in religious texts

Comment: 1. I wouldn't be worried that it is not so popular, everybody understands it and it is _[rising in frequency of use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vanity%2C+vain&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvanity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvain%3B%2Cc0) lately. Otherwise have a look at its [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/vanity).

Comment: 2. In the Bible "vanity" is used rather with the meaning of "the quality of being worthless or futile". To refer to your concept, later religious texts use _**[vainglory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vainglory)**_ that some consider dated, or at least literary...

Comment: Also, for 1. [_conceit_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceit) may be more common.

Comment: The word vain is common enough to be in a #1 hit: Carly Simon - You're So Vain "You're so vain, I bet you think this song is about you"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQZmCJUSC6g

Comment: Hm, I typically see vanity used as meaning "inflated pride in oneself or one's appearance", which is more related to *one's own* internal sense of worth, rather than having to do with *external* validation. To me, vanity is more "I think I'm great" than "I want other people to think I'm great". A vain person thinks about themselves far more than others, although I agree there can be a subconscious element of wanting external approval.

Comment: I wouldn't say people "seek vanity", I would say people "are vain" or "seek admiration". Posting insta stories of your private jet is vain because you're looking for approval from the masses. You might have a "vanity instagram account" which shows the cool places you go. However, vain people probably don't think of themselves as vain, just cool/fortunate/rich/beautiful etc., so to them it's just their insta account, even if its purpose is actually vanity.

Comment: This was a great paragraph demonstrating the usage of different forms of vanity in context. Well done!

Answer (score 13):

Neediness/someone who is needy. Per [TheFreeDictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neediness), "the quality of needing attention and affection and reassurance to a marked degree". Just be careful using this because it's a very negative way to describe someone so it's not acceptable in a formal context (or if you still want to be friends with them later).

Comment: This doesn't really work. If you're talking about a needy child I'm imagining a child who cries a lot and can't be left alone, not one per se that's seeking validation or popularity. In the same way, a needy scientist is probably someone who asks a lot of questions and needs a bunch of favors, neither of which necessarily means they want their research (or themselves) to be more popular.

Comment: @Laurel -- "Needy" is often used in a sense of wanting validation from others.  Of course, the context would have to suggest this sense.

Comment: I think this is the best suggestion so far, though, as previously mentioned, it is a bit muddied by also being used for other purposes.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest **narcissism**:

> ... people have an inflated sense of their own importance, a deep need for excessive attention and admiration, troubled relationships, and a lack of empathy for others.
> [Mayo clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/narcissistic-personality-disorder/symptoms-causes/syc-20366662#:%7E:text=Overview,lack%20of%20empathy%20for%20others.)

It implies more than just what you are looking for, but I think it fairly accurately hits the need for *excessive need* from your question.

Comment: As narcissism is a medical diagnosis, and diagnosing others outside of a medical/therapy setting is a not-great idea, I'd suggest to not use this one. Unless this is in a fictional piece from a writer, using narcissism to describe real people is inaccurate without diagnosis, and misleading.

Comment: @Andrea Is ‘narcissism’ not used in general, non-medical ways too?

Comment: @Andrea: Narcissistic personality disorder is a medical diagnosis. Narcissism is a personality trait that everybody possesses to one degree or another.

Comment: @Andrea >> 'narcissism is a medical diagnosis'.  [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/narcissism-symptoms-signs) says '[no](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/narcissistic-personality-disorder)'.  Narcissus was just someone who loved himself.  You may want to look at the '[Controversies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism)' section on wikipedia

Comment: Whether or not narcissism is a medical diagnosis is beside the point, as narcissists definitely _don't_ seek external validation. Everything they need is found within themselves.

Comment: @Auspex According to [at least one therapist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1NUZ0XspA4&t=90), for the medical diagnosis Narcissistic Personality Disorder to apply, an excessive need for admiration is one of the key aspects. I see no reason the personality trait of narcissism would differ here. The medical diagnosis (like many mental disorder diagnoses) is just having the personality trait to such a degree that it interferes with and hinders your daily life.

Answer (score 4):

Since you added one more nuance in a *[comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593191/what-is-a-single-word-that-describes-excessive-human-desire-for-external-vali/593194#comment1491051_593194)* it is more clear what kind of word you are looking for. You say

> I am referring to a very recent and popular trend of seeking large-scale status and popularity by say having high social media followers.

You could use then ***attention-seeker***

> someone who behaves in a way that will attract other people's attention. ([macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/attention-seeker#:%7E:text=attention%20seekers,me%20as%20an%20attention%20seeker.))

It is a relatively recent word and very common, I find it used without a hyphen too. You will find an entry and synonyms for it in the *[UrbanDictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=attention%20seeker)*, and I am mentioning that just to show how popular it is. It is also used as a noun, ***attention seeking***. About it, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_seeking) says

> *Attention seeking* behavior is to act in a way that is likely to elicit attention. Attention seeking behavior is defined in the DSM-5 as "***engaging in behavior designed to attract notice and to make oneself the focus of others’ attention and admiration***".  The term "attention seeking" sometimes also assumes a motive of ***seeking validation***. People are thought to engage in both positive and negative attention seeking behaviour independent of the actual benefit or harm to health.

However, although this term is said to have both positive and neutral connotations depending on context, it is definitely used pejoratively most of the time.

Even dictionaries show that

> Attention-seeker: A person who tries to get attention, ***typically*** in a manner considered ***excessive*** or ***inappropriate***. ([yourdict](https://www.yourdictionary.com/attention-seeker))

Here are some *[synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/attention-seeker.html)* of the term.

Answer (score 3):

**Obsequiousness** may fit some aspects of the desire for validation, indicating servile obedience or an over-eagerness to please. An obsequious individual will go to excessive lengths to please others. It may not exactly describe the *desire* for external validation, but it does describe the *behavior* that one is willing to exhibit to get it. Not everyone who desires validation is obsequious, but everyone who is obsequious desires validation.

Answer (score 1):

**Insecurity**.

As per the first [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/insecurity) definition:

> 1. lack of confidence or assurance; self-doubt:
>    *He is plagued by insecurity.*

How well this word fits will depend on your specific use case. Insecurity doesn't describe the behaviour so much as the cause. However, as a human weakness, I think it works with your listed examples of lust and gluttony.

Answer (score -1):

Egotism, narcissism, attention-seeking. Often a result of low self-esteem and/or of over-estimating the value of being the center of attention.

Answer (score -2):

Well for girls there is **pick-me girl**: A girl who craves male attention and tries to be "not like other girls". Idk the word for boys tho.